# Pick numbers from an array and see if they are even and lower than 380

Tags: bash

I'm programing a bash to pick all numbers from a list and print all even and lower than 380.
This is what i have so far, but i get error on if...

Any help is welcome.

```
n=(951 402 984 651 360 69 408 319 601 485 980 507 725 547 544 615 141 501 263 617 865 575 219 390 237 412 566 826 248 866 950 626 949 687 217 815 67 104 58 512 24 892 894 767 553)

for (( i=0; i<${#n[@]}; i++ ))
 do
  b=${n[$i]}
  rem=$(( $b % 2 ))
  if (( $rem == 0 && b < 380 ))
    then
      echo "$b Par"
    else
     continue
  fi
done
```

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there. One space after `[` and before `]` is important.

Comment: Syntax aside, when is `b` *not* going to be less than `b + 1`?

Comment: I suggest to switch to a `for` loop: `for ((i=0; i<${#n[@]}; i++)); do echo "${n[$i]}"; done`

Comment: Ok, i'm correcting the syntax. I want the program to read all numbers one by one and see if he is even (pair) and lower than 380.

Comment: I made some changes, and can read the numbers, but getting error on if condition

Comment: The line `rem=$(( $n % 2 ))` should be `rem=$(( b % 2 ))` and the next line should be `if [ $rem -eq 0 -a $b -lt 380 ]`. The expression is outdated and better to say `if (( rem == 0 && b < 380 ))`.

Comment: I know what is the problem on if condition. It's the &&. But i want the if condition to have the two conditons, it must be a pair number and lower than 380 to print the number.

Comment: My bad, i dont have n on my bash i have b, sorry i edited but put wrong letter